# GORM create record with foreign key

Tags: go, insert

Can't make record that refers to existed row.

I have two tables and one table references on another one. Table "Category" is already existed. I try to add new record on "Heritage" table but gorm try to do new record at Category.

```
type Category struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name string `gorm:"unique"`
}

type Site struct {
    gorm.Model
    Category         Category `gorm:"foreignkey:CategoryID"`
    DateInscribed    string
    HttpURL          string
    Latitude         float32
    Location         string
    Longitude        float32
    SecondaryDates   string
    ShortDescription string
    Site             string
}
```

As I say "Category" table is existed with all I needed rows. I try to do Site record but get issue "define a valid foreign key for relations or implement the Valuer/Scanner interface".

With this code I try to make record.

```
site := &models.Site{
    Category:         models.Category{Name: heritage.Category},
    DateInscribed:    heritage.DateInscribed,
    HttpURL:          heritage.HttpURL,
    Latitude:         heritage.Latitude,
    Location:         heritage.Location,
    Longitude:        heritage.Longitude,
    SecondaryDates:   heritage.SecondaryDates,
    ShortDescription: heritage.ShortDescription,
}

db.Create(site)
```

Seems I try to make new record on Category table but needed only add category_id value to Site record.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you don't store the `Name` as a foreign key, but the `ID` value.
For that you need to add a new field `CategoryID` in Site of type `uint`:

```
type Site struct {
    gorm.Model
    Category         Category
    CategoryID       uint
    DateInscribed    string
    ...
}
```

This field will be automatically linked to the Category table, so if you use the default name, you don't need to write `gorm:"foreignKey:CategoryID"`.

Then to create a Site object, you can do it in this way:

```
site := &models.Site{
    CategoryID: id,
    DateInscribed:    heritage.DateInscribed,
    ...
}
db.Create(site)
```

If you want to reuse the existing table Category, you will need to find the ID from name:

```
var id uint
db.Model(&models.Category{}).Where("name = ?", name).Select("ID").First(&id)
```

For me it is not clear from the [GORM documentation](https://gorm.io/docs/belongs_to.html#Override-References) what to do if you want to reference the Name field, maybe someone else can answer.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I decide that gorm maybe supports more sneaky way to do it, but nvm. This method works very good, thanks for help!